# How to host multiple flutter web apps in parallel

Tags: flutter-web

Lets say I have two flutter web apps; Admin and Users. I'd like to host them at the same location. The files structure:

```
/Admin  
  /Assets  
  /Icons  
  /index.html
  /manifest.json
  /main.dart.js
  ...
/Users
  /Assets  
  /Icons  
  /index.html
  /manifest.json
  /main.dart.js
  ...
```

The problem currently is that `flutter build web` does not allow for a relative path and thus files are expected to be relative to the root and not to the `index.html` or any other file.

If I could pass the relative path (something like: `flutter build web -path /Admin`) that would solve the problem. Or if the paths would be relative and not absolute.

Is there currently a solution?